# Installing and configuring SQlite Browser on LINUX

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to Linux, and I don't know how to install sqlite-autoconf-3070400 and SQlite database browser in my Linux OS.
Please give step wise details. I want it for Android Development. So do I need some extra?

---

*This was the question about to view database. I asked this question because I had no idea how can I view db contents. I was aware and used other DB so was thinking that there might be a GUI for SQlite too. 
As I got my answer and added too for future. So be honest while downvoting this question.*

Comment: Are you sure its not there already? Its pretty hard these days to have linux run without it.

Comment: Interesting!!!! Someone has been downvoted... May I know why you did??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is alternative solution for SQlite browser...
(Actually all LINUX machines having SQlite allready, You need only GUI of SQlite. Sqlite database browser is predefined option. But when you unable to install it(like me) then go for this another solution ...
You have to add addon to firefox. You can download it from 
http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/
and for installing this addon (after downloaded it) press "ctrl+o" > choose downloaded file > open > install.

Now after restarting Firefox, go to Tools > SQLite Manager > open it and choose your database to open and do your work.

---

***Update for `sqlite3`***

---

Android has given a very good tool, which is *sqlite3*. You can find this tool into **`sdk/tool/`** directory.

***Introduction :-***

*From an `adb` remote shell, you can use the `sqlite3` command-line program to manage SQLite databases created by Android applications. The sqlite3 tool includes many useful commands, such as `.dump` to print out the contents of a table and `.schema` to print the `SQL CREATE` statement for an existing table. The tool also gives you the ability to execute SQLite commands on the fly.*

*To use `sqlite3`, enter a remote shell on the emulator instance, as described above, then invoke the tool using the sqlite3 command. Optionally, when invoking sqlite3 you can specify the full path to the database you want to explore. Emulator/device instances store `SQLite3` databases in the folder `/data/data/<package_name>/databases/`.*

Here's an example:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 shell
# sqlite3 /data/data/com.example.google.rss.rssexample/databases/rssitems.db
SQLite version 3.3.12
Enter ".help" for instructions
.... enter commands, then quit...
sqlite> .exit
```

*Once you've invoked `sqlite3`, you can issue `sqlite3` commands in the shell. To exit and return to the adb remote shell, use exit or `CTRL+D`.*

Read more at [Examining sqlite3 databases from a remote shell](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#sqlite)

Happy coding!

Answer (score 4):

Kinda old but u do have SQLite Browser on Linux. I dont get it why didnt someone paste this.
for example, Ubuntu based:

For Ubuntu and derivaties, @deepsidhu1313 provides a PPA with our latest release here:

```
https://launchpad.net/~linuxgndu/+archive/ubuntu/sqlitebrowser
```

To add this ppa just type in these commands in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser
```

Then update the cache using:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the package using:

```
sudo apt-get install sqlitebrowser
```

Ubuntu 14.04.X, 15.04.X, 15.10.X and 16.04.X are supported for now (until Launchpad decides to discontinue build for any series).

You can find rest on the home page http://sqlitebrowser.org/
Scroll down or CTRL F for linux installing :)

Comment: Hey @Marko I followed these steps but after this where is visual editor? Where it is installed on ubuntu?

Comment: It's been a while since I did this but it's probably right there in apps, just search it? It shouldn't be any different than installing other apps in Ubuntu....

Answer (score 1):

Here are commands needed to executed to install sqlite Browser

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-qmake cmake libsqlite3-dev libqt4-dev libqt4-core libqt4-qt3support
wget http://optimate.dl.sourceforge.net/project/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/3.2/sqlitebrowser-3.2.0.tar.gz
tar -xvf sqlitebrowser-3.2.0.tar.gz
cd sqlitebrowser-sqlb-3.2.0/
qmake    
make
```